# How To Get Children of Xamarin Forms Listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I currently developing a listview in Xamarin.

In every cell i got a scrollView and i am trying to scroll each of them same amount when one of them scrolled.

And i trying to get all scrollviews in children of listview and scroll them any scroll event triggered.

Or is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do something like this (embedding scrolling containers into already scrolling ones is generally discouraged), but you made me think about a possible approach. :-)

Cells of a `ListView` are being generated dynamically. I'd probably use the [messaging service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/). You can send out a message about the position you'd like all of your cells to scroll to like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<ViewCell, float> (this, "ScrollPosChanged", currentScrollPos);
```

and then subscribe in your custom cells:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ViewCell, float> (this, "ScrollPosChanged", (sender, arg) => {
  // Scroll this cell's scrollview.
});
```

Comment: Great to know about this feature thanks. Just don't forget to UnSubscribe in custom cell.